# John 6:40; what is the meaning of "everlasting life", "I will raise him up at the Last day"?

Tags: john, eschatology

John 6:40; KJV;

> 40 And this is the will of him that sent me, that every one which seeth the Son, and believeth on him, **may have everlasting life**: and **I will raise him up** at the last day.

What is the meaning of "I Will raise him up at the Last day"?

Does this mean that the **unbelievers** will not be raised up in the last day?, At least for condemnation?

Does this mean that the **unbelievers** will be raised up for condemnation, but they will not have **everlasting life**?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is given in the previous chapter where Jesus discusses the same topic.

> John 5:24-29 - **24** Truly, truly, I tell you, whoever hears My word
> and believes Him who sent Me **has eternal life** and will not come
> under judgment. Indeed, he has crossed over from death to life.
>
> **25** Truly, truly, I tell you, the hour is coming and has now come when the dead will hear the voice of the Son of God, and those who
> hear will live. **26** For as the Father has life in Himself, so also
> He has granted the Son to have life in Himself. **27** And He has
> given Him authority to execute judgment, because He is the Son of Man.
>
> **28** Do not be amazed at this, for the hour is coming when all who are in their graves will hear His voice **29** and come out—those who
> have done good to the resurrection of life, and those who have done
> evil to the resurrection of damnation.

We have other material on the same topic:

> 1 John 5:11, 12 - And this is that testimony: God has given us eternal
> life, and this life is in His Son. Whoever has the Son has life;
> whoever does not have the Son of God does not have life.

> Dan 12:1, 2 - “At that time Michael, the great prince who stands watch
> over your people, will rise up. There will be a time of distress, the
> likes of which will not have occurred from the beginning of nations
> until that time. But at that time your people—everyone whose name is
> found written in the book—will be delivered.
>
> And many who sleep in the dust of the earth will awake, some to
> everlasting life, but others to shame and everlasting contempt.

> Rev 11:18 - The nations were enraged, and Your wrath has come. The
> time has come to judge the dead and to reward Your servants the
> prophets, as well as the saints and those who fear Your name, both
> small and great— and to destroy those who destroy the earth.”

This is entirely consistent with Jesus' teaching about the great eschatological resurrection as recorded in John 6:39, 40, 44 -

> And this is the will of Him who sent Me, that I shall lose none of
> those He has given Me, but raise them up at the last day. For it is My
> Father’s will that everyone who looks to the Son and believes in Him
> shall have eternal life, and I will raise him up at the last day.” ...
> “No one can come to Me unless the Father who sent Me draws him, and I
> will raise him up at the last day.

Thus, while righteous faithful will be raised at the last day to be with God forever, the wicked will be raised to be eternally condemned.

> 1 John 2:17 - The world is passing away, along with its desires; but
> whoever does the will of God remains forever.

> 2 Peter 3:13 - But in keeping with God’s promise, we are looking
> forward to a new heaven and a new earth, where righteousness dwells.

> Rev 22:3-5 - No longer will there be any curse. The throne of God and
> of the Lamb will be within the city, and His servants will worship
> Him. They will see His face, and His name will be on their foreheads.
> There will be no more night in the city, and they will have no need
> for the light of a lamp or of the sun. For the Lord God will shine on
> them, and they will reign forever and ever.

Comment: John said: everlasting life for the believers, not everlasting glory or everlasting life (with the Father). I hope you understand me.

Comment: @salah - I am not sure I understand your point.

Comment: if John said: the believers may have everlasting life, this exegetically means: the unbelievers may Not have everlasting life. But if he said: the believers may have everlasting glory, for example, this exegetically means: the unbelievers may have everlasting life, but without glory. I hope now my point is clear.

Comment: @salah  Jesus is The Life (Jn.11:25). All who belong to him by faith receive the life everlasting that is in him, thus he could say that they HAVE everlasting life and shall not come into condemnation, but have passed from death unto life... He that believes on me HAS everlasting life (Jn.5:24 & 6:47). Those who don't are raised to eternal condemnation. Rev.20:11-15 is clear that all the dead will be resurrected but only those whose names are in the Lamb's book of Life will have everlasting glory with God. All others will have everlasting experience of the lake of fire, away from God.

Answer (score 1):

The NT belief in the Son's authority over the father in [John 6:40] of KJV (from Textus Receptus) is highlighted by English text's Uppercase "[Son] υἱὸν" and lowercase "[him] τοῦ [that sent] πέμψαντος [me] με" - clearly the glory is desired by Jesus here :

KJV [John 6:40] "And this is the will of him that sent me, that every one which seeth the Son, and believeth on him, may have everlasting life: and I will raise him up at the last day." (6:40  τοῦτο δὲ ἐστιν τὸ θέλημα τοῦ πέμψαντος με, ἵνα πᾶς ὁ θεωρῶν τὸν υἱὸν καὶ πιστεύων εἰς αὐτὸν ἔχῃ ζωὴν αἰώνιον καὶ ἀναστήσω αὐτὸν ἐγὼ τῇ ἐσχάτῃ ἡμέρᾳ)

**But the NKJV amends the disrespect to the Father, by Uppercasing "[Him] τοῦ" :**

NKJV [John 6:40] - “And this is the will of Him who sent Me, that everyone who sees the Son and believes in Him may have everlasting life; and I will raise him up at the last day.”

**What is the meaning of "I Will raise him up at the Last day" - when considering [Matthew 24:31, 1 Thesselonians 4:16, Revelation 14:13]?**

The Last Day of earthly existence for a soul which consciously consumed Jesus' teachings (flesh of his Word) [John 6:54-56] would warrant the Father to recognize part of His son's soul remained on earth & send his son back [Acts 1:11] to collect portions of himself (believers) that got scattered across earth.

**Based on the logic of [John 6:54-56], the resurrected soul of Jesus is not 100% in heaven. - Which means in [John 6:40] Jesus only returns to save what's left of himself.**